# Does $ab=ba$ and $(ab)c=a(bc)$ imply $(ab)(cd)=((ab)c)d$?

Tags: proof-writing, arithmetic

Say we have proven the commutative and associative multiplicative property of the natural numbers. How can we from here prove that given an equation

$$(...(k_1k_2)k_3)...)k_n)$$

, where the $k_i$ are natural numbers, that the order of multiplication doesn't matter?

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course, even without first identity.

Just $$(ab)(cd)=((ab)c)d.$$
With the first identity order of numbers doesn't matter.

Comment: Yeah, I see it now (with that specific example). But how could it be generalized so that given a general equation as the one posted the order of multiplication wouldn't matter at all?

Comment: It's just induction.

Comment: I've been trying to do induction for a while now, but having been able to achieve anything

Answer (score 0):

We need to show
\begin{eqnarray*}
k_1 k_2 \cdots k_n = k_{ \sigma(1)} k_{ \sigma(2)} \cdots k_{ \sigma(n)} 
\end{eqnarray*}
for any permutation $ \sigma \in S_n$ and any order of the multiplications.

Associativity give that the order of the multiplications will give the same answer.

Commutativity & the fact that any permutation can be expressed as the porduct of adjacent transpositions will give that the product will be independent of the order of the elements.